# ASP MVC css/js bundles: length & name of bundle parameter "?v=1234567890"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bundle

in ASP MVC you can use the bundles function.

The code will result typically in something like:

```
/js/jquery?v=1A_Qqa6eu1hIFc9O--lfxRqvbqGj9Zd6uAr93zLdrWM1
```

Is there any option to control the name of the parameter "v" and to control the length of the token?

Lets say im looking forward to a shorter version with a pattern like:

```
/js/jquery?x=3457936
```

Is there any option to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any option to control the name of the parameter "v" and to
>   control the length of the token?

No, there isn't. Those values are hardcoded in the `System.Web.Optimization` assembly. Here's an excerpt from an internal method that does this:

```
internal string GetBundleUrl(BundleContext context, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(true)] bool includeContentHash)
{
    string bundleVirtualPath = context.BundleVirtualPath;
    if (includeContentHash)
    {
        bundleVirtualPath = bundleVirtualPath + "?v=" + this.GetBundleResponse(context).GetContentHashCode();
    }
    return AssetManager.GetInstance(context.HttpContext).ResolveVirtualPath(bundleVirtualPath);
}
```

The `GetContentHashCode` method calculates the SHA256 checksum of the file contents.